# The set of third roots of $-8$, and the set of fourth roots of $-i$. What does this mean?

Tags: definition, roots

> Calculate the sets of
>
> (a) the third roots of $-8$, and (b) the fourth roots of $-i$.

The problem is we did not get any definition we can rely on, no number sets given, just the text above, but I think we should do it for the real numbers. How would you do that, on which definition would you rely on? We did nothing regarding roots.

Comment: Where else do you think those roots would be?

Comment: What do you know about powers of complex numbers?

Comment: I did not realy understand what you mean. For a) I would only have the solution -2 for b) I do not really no. I could use the definition the nth root of -i = (-i)^(1/n). I do not think that i is a complex number cause we didnt had complex numbers

Comment: @N74 Nothing, I do not now whether complex numbers is meant because we did not really have that number set but that i implicates that it could be a complex number

Comment: If the question involves $i$, then the question is about complex numbers. If you haven't covered them yet, then any responses you get here are not likely to make much sense to you.

Comment: @Blue Yeah, I am always confused. Exercises which do not cover what the lecture covers but I will try to understand it. For a) what should I do there if the only solution is -2 when I rely on my knowledge

Comment: Can you show, what you would have done? Would you just write the set of a) is {-2} for real numbers? And what would b) look like?

Comment: Mohammad's answer below is more-or-less the standard way to approach the problem. A full lesson in complex roots is generally beyond the scope of this site. Try some web searches for lessons on the "roots of unity" (that's the fancy way of saying "roots of $1$"); once you understand those, the roots of other real numbers are fairly straightforward.

Comment: @Blue Thank you, I will try to understand it!

Answer (score 0):

If your third roots of $-8$ is $re^{i\theta } $, then $$r^3 e^{3i\theta} = -8 = 8 e^{i\pi}$$

You need to solve for r and all possible solutions of $\theta$ which give you three distinct roots of $-8$

Similarly for the fourth roots of $-i$, you want $$r^4 e^{4i\theta}= -i = e^{3i\pi/2}$$

Comment: Wow, we did not cover that. Could you send a link to understand what you have written? First solve the solution for r then for the symbol 0 (do not know how to write it or what that symbol means)

Comment: @D.Dave       just google the $ n_{th}$ roots on unity and you get it .

Comment: I will! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Thank you for your attention.